# Find sequence in two Numpy arrays

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, numpy, sequence

I have two Numpy arrays which contain indices of maxima and minima from another array.

For example, for one output, the maxima and minima arrays look like this:

```
Maxima indices are (array([ 4, 10, 14, 37, 43, 51, 59, 67, 81, 89, 95]),)
Minima indices are (array([ 7, 12, 25, 33, 40, 49, 56, 63, 76, 92]),)
```

These indices come from intensity values in an image row.

I need to find how many times a maxima occurs within four index positions between two minima - in other words:

```
minima + 4 + maxima + 4 + minima
```

How can I do this efficiently in Python?  How can I compare the index values in both arrays to find instances of this sequence and then count how many instances there are in total?

Many thanks for any help.

**EDIT:**  Each maximum has to be within 4 positions of the closest minima on the left and the right.  Basically I am trying to identify a dotted line within an image based on intensity values.

Comment: Does the maximum have to be within 4 positions of closest minima on the left and on the right? Or is it enough that it is within 4 positions of one minimum?

Comment: The maximum has to be within 4 positions of the closest minima on the left and the right - yes.  I will edit the question to reflect this.  Thanks for asking.

Comment: Ok, the code in my answer should take it into account. It just makes one-way traversal impossible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us try.

```
import numpy

# create a vector for distances from the nearest leftmost minimum
# img_len is the length of the image row

# first we create an integer vector with 1 at each minimum
b = numpy.zeros(img_len, dtype='int')

# then we create an integer vector for the distances
d = numpy.zeros(img_len, dtype='int')

# we mark leftmost distances up to the first minimum to be largest possible
d[:minima[0]] = minima[0] - numpy.arange(minima[0])

# then we iterate through the vector and calculate the distances
for i in range(len(minima) - 1):
    prev = minima[i]
    next = minima[i+1]
    # now we have a gap between the two minima
    # let's fill it with a triangle 0,1,2,...,2,1,0
    k = (next-prev + 1) // 2
    d[prev:prev+k+1] = numpy.arange(k+1)
    d[next-k+1:next] = k -1 - numpy.arange(k-1)

# fill in the space after the last minimum:
d[minima[-1]:] = numpy.arange(img_len - minima[-1])

# all maxima whose distance is less than D from the closest minimum
results = [ m for m in maxima if d[m] < D ]
```

Unless it is evident form the code, the idea is to create a vector `d` which corresponds to the distance from the nearest minimum. The resulting vector is, e.g., 4,3,2,1,0,1,2,3,2,1,0,1,2,1,0,... where the zeros correspond to the minima positions. The most difficult thing is to get the triangle-making in the loop right. (I hope I cleaned all off-by-ones...)

Of course, now you can also make a list of tuples for the maxima positions:

```
[ (m, d[m]) for m in maxima ]
```

For the data in the question this returns:

```
[(4, 3),
 (10, 2),
 (14, 2),
 (37, 3),
 (43, 3),
 (51, 2),
 (59, 3),
 (67, 4),
 (81, 5),
 (89, 3),
 (95, 3)]
```

The code works even if there are more than one maxima between two minima as in the question. (If there were only a single maximum, then the code would be almost completely different.)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.  I am getting an error with the code: d[:minima[0]] = minima[0] - np.arange(minima[0]) - only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars.  The array of minima is the output of minima = argrelextrema(img_row, np.less) where img_row is the Numpy array of pixel intensity values for a horizontal line of the image in question.  Can you help?

Comment: What does your python say, if you ask `type(minima[0])`? And what does it say for `type(minima)` and `minima.shape` and `len(minima)`?

Comment: type(minima[0]) = <type 'numpy.ndarray'> type(minima) = <type 'tuple'> minima.shape = AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'shape' len(minima) = 1

Comment: Yup. Try: `minima = argrelexrema(img_row, np.less)[0]` (and similar [0] for maxima). This is because `argrelextrema` returns a list of outputs. From the doc of `argrelextrema`: "Note that the return value is a tuple even when data is one-dimensional."

Comment: Tried that.  Now I get an error - results = [ m for m in maxima if d[m] < 5 ]
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

Comment: What do `type(maxima)` and `maxima.shape` say? (We are almost there!)

Comment: I had forgotten to select maxima[0].  It works now!  Thanks for all your detailed help - much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'll put this as another answer, as this is a completely different method. Not very space-eficient, but very short code, and very numpyish.

```
import numpy

# let's assume minima and maxima are 1-d arrays
# then the distance matrix for distances between any maximum to any minimum is:
md = numpy.amin(numpy.abs(maxima[:,None]-minima[None,:]), axis=1)

# the maxima which are at most D pixels away form the closest minima:
cm = maxima[md < D]
```

And these can of course be combined into a one-liner which is very difficult to understand.

Brief explanation:

- a matrix of distances between all minima (columns) and maxima (rows) is calculated (full of redundant and irrelevant information)
- absolute value of the matrix gives the distance between each maximum to each minimum
- the shortest distance from each maximum to any minimum is taken with the `amin` operation along a row
- `cm` is calculated by indexing the maxima with a boolean array (Trues where the distance is below the limit)

If the vectors are long, this may become slow. If there is no hurry, this is a simple piece of code.